# List<object> To List<T> using reflection

Tags: c#, json

I'm rolling a json converter and I have properties decorated with a mapping designation.  I'm using reflection to use that mapping description to determine what kind of object to create and how it maps.  Below is an example...

```
[JsonMapping("location", JsonMapping.MappingType.Class)]
    public Model.Location Location { get; set; }
```

My mapping works fine until I get to a collection...

```
[JsonMapping("images", JsonMapping.MappingType.Collection)]
    public IList<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

The problem is that I cant' convert List to the list type of the property.

```
private static List<object> Map(Type t, JArray json) {

        List<object> result = new List<object>();
        var type = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        foreach (var j in json) {
            result.Add(Map(type, (JObject)j));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

That returns me the List, but reflection wants me to implement IConvertable before doing a property.SetValue.

Anybody know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably doesn't make a difference, but have you tried changing the return type of Map to IList<object> instead (or vice versa)?

Comment: You would need contravariance support for `IList<T>` in order to do that. C# doesn't have that so you cannot assign `IList<string> list = new List<object>();`

Comment: Well, i could change the type to IList<object>, but I want it to be of type IList<User> or whatever type I specify so that when people use the library, things are neatly mapped for them.

Comment: Did you take a look at [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) yet? This library might do what you need.

Comment: :) - It's using Json.NET to convert the json string to an object.  I'm just trying to take it a step further and do some custom mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create `List` object of the correct type using [Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx):

```
private static IList Map(Type t, JArray json)
{
    var elementType = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // This will produce List<Image> or whatever the original element type is
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
    var result = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

    foreach (var j in json)
        result.Add(Map(type, (JObject)j));

    return result;    
}
```